# Pandas dummies using list of categories encoded as string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I have a dataframe of the format:

```
id    amenities                     ...
1     "TV,Internet,Shower,..."      ...
2     "TV,Hot tub,Internet,..."     ...
3     "Internet,Heating,Shower..."  ...
...
```

I want to split the string about the commas and create dummy columns for each category, resulting in something like this:

```
id    TV    Internet    Shower    Hot tub    Heating    ...
1     1     1           1         0          0          ...
2     1     1           0         1          0          ...
3     0     1           1         0          1          ...
...
```

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = df[['id']].join(df['amentieis'].str.get_dummies(','))
print (df)
   id  Heating  Hot tub  Internet  Shower  TV
0   1        0        0         1       1   1
1   2        0        1         1       0   1
2   3        1        0         1       1   0
```

Or:

```
df = pd.concat([df['id'], df['amentieis'].str.get_dummies(',')], axis=1)
print (df)
   id  Heating  Hot tub  Internet  Shower  TV
0   1        0        0         1       1   1
1   2        0        1         1       0   1
2   3        1        0         1       1   0
```